# Optimising Obj loading in Three JS

Tags: 3d, three.js

I am trying to optimise the loading of OBJ from the THREE JS OBJMTLLoader. I load the obj through the standard technique and I am trying to apply ShaderMaterial by cloning the existing material in the OBJ.

Is this the right technique? The objective is to load the OBJ through the GPU instead of using CPU cycles.

I am also try my hands on the WebGL code but that will take time. Would this be the correct approach?

Following is the dummy code. I know that some ShaderMaterial code has to be added related to uniforms and attributes.

```
var loader = new THREE.OBJMTLLoader();
    loader.load(objModel, mtlModel, function(object) {
                object.position.x = 20;
                object.position.y = -20;
                object.position.z = -100;

                object.scale.set(10, 10, 10);
                object.matrixAutoUpdate = false;
                object.updateMatrix();
                var testMat;

        object.traverse( function ( child ) {
                     var object3d = child;
                     if(object3d instanceof THREE.Mesh){
                        testMat = new THREE.ShaderMaterial();
                        testMat.copy(object3d.material);
                        object3d.material = testMat;
                        object3d.geometry.computeFaceNormals();
                        object3d.geometry.computeTangents();
                        object3d.geometry.computeBoundingSphere();
                     }
        });
});
```

Comment: loading the .obj will always be through the CPU. displaying the .obj will always be through the GPU (as shaders are used internally in three.js)

Comment: So, obj is always rendered using the GPU? Would writing a core WebGL code improve performance?

Comment: how big is your object (space-wise)?

Comment: 1 MB is the size of the obj

Answer (score 1):

If you mean "I want to optimize the loading time" then the first thing you should do is convert the text OBJ file(s) to a binary file and json stub. You can use the tool provided with THREE.js, you will find it in `../three.js/utils/converters/obj/convert_obj.py` -- run this on your obj file and it will generate a `.bin` (buffers) and `.js` (materials) equivalent. You can then use THREE's `JSONLoader` and `BinaryLoader` objects to load fetch the model. It will be *much* faster. Further detail docs are in the header of the `.py` file

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will check this today.